# Identify IC marked `Y3KS`

Tags: diodes, voltage-regulator, identification, zener, led-driver

Can anyone help me identify following IC?

[image]
[image]

Comment: There are SMD code search sites suggesting a TLVH431BIDBZT voltage regulator.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the IC?

Comment: If dimensions match, perhaps Toshiba PNP transistor RN2131F? [datasheet](http://www.elenota.pl/datasheet_download/131100/RN2131F)  Can you show some more of the board and the surrounding parts, that really helps give context

Comment: Most definitely a wider angle picture is needed - this part can literally be anything, but with some context it should be possible to narrow down the possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [Texas Instruments TLVH431BIDBZT](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlvh431b.pdf) voltage reference (as commented by greybeard).

- The markings match:
  [image]
- The marking style matches:

[image]
(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Voltage-References_Texas-Instruments-TLVH431BIDBZR_C131986.html))

- The "D" designator and the pinout matches:

[image]
(Source: datasheet, see above)

Comment: Thank you, I think it right

Comment: @HNLinh If you think the answer is correct, please accept it with the [checkmark symbol](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour).